# Headless Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

while not using the headless option, Everything works as intended, but while using the headless option it cannot find the elements requested. Here is the specific line of code that cannot identify in headless but can while it's not.

```
type_entry = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, type_)))
type_entry.location_once_scrolled_into_view
type_entry.click()
```

Also, here a list of options I'm using:

```
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

The error is that it's timing out The WebDriverWait, and it's not able to find the element. Without headless it functions normally.

I have tried editing options, changing the XPATH and using element_to_be_clickable